# Jekyll site doesn't show theme

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

So when i initially first post the site from cmd `bundle exec jekyll serve` it is ok and well but when i upload to github it shows like in [image: this] picture.
I have tried re-doing the whole thing twice but to no avail. I will be very thankful to someone who has more experience in this helping me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your description without looking at the code, but it may have to do with github's jekyll configuration. One thing I noticed is that github does not process any directory starting with _, hence if any of your HTML is in one of these (such as _assets) it will not create a corresponding page